# QtGui.QColor does't work when I give it a list [..., ..., ..., ...] as a function argument

Tags: python, pyqt5

I need help with `PyQt`.
I have a simple `PyQt` widget as an example. It has a plain color for background.  But I don't understand why it shows black color when I give it a list for color argument  `__init__ (self, color = [100, 150 ,200 ,255])`.

But I want it to show color correctly by sending only list of numbers to color argument.

I'm trying to convert this list into a string and then send it to `self.p.setColor()`. But it doesn't work either. Shows only black color as a background.

But if I send `QtGui.QColor(150, 200, 100, 255)` directly to color argument it works.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class ColorBox(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, color = [100, 200, 150, 255]):

        super(ColorBox, self).__init__()

        self.CoCo = ",".join(str(i) for i in color)
        print (self.CoCo)

        self.setFixedSize(200, 200)

        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.p = self.palette()
        self.p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), QtGui.QColor(self.CoCo))
        self.setPalette(self.p)
        self.setObjectName("Color_cube")


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = ColorBox()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So this does't work:

```
def __init__(self, color = [100, 200, 150, 255]):
```

But this works fine if I send color attr directly to self.p.setColor():

```
def __init__(self, color = QtGui.QColor(100, 200, 150, 255):
```

What should I do to make first variant work just by converting somehow list of numbers into color values? Cause I need to store this color argument in JSON file. And I can't store whole this line `"QtGui.QColor(100, 200, 150, 255)"`

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class ColorBox(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, color = [100, 200, 150, 255]):

        super(ColorBox, self).__init__()

        if isinstance(color, (list, tuple) ):
            myColor = QtGui.QColor( *color )
        elif isinstance( color, QtGui.QColor ):
            myColor = color
        else:
            raise TypeError

        self.setFixedSize(200, 200)

        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.p = self.palette()
        self.p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), myColor )
        self.setPalette(self.p)
        self.setObjectName("Color_cube")


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ###all three work
    # ~ main = ColorBox()
    # ~ main = ColorBox( (30,0,180,250) )
    main = ColorBox( QtGui.QColor( 250, 0, 180, 250 ) )
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In case of a `list` or `tuple` you locally create the `QColor` by **unpacking** them. If it is a `QColor` already you leave it.